# AJAX Block CORS - CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

Previously the application could run well, but after changing the Xampp version, it can no longer be used

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://[::1]/down/index.php/person/ajax_list' from origin 'http://localhost' has been a header is present on the requested resource.

> Blockquote
>   [Error Report form Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWNcj.png)

Comment: You need to enable CORS at server side, or try requesting API with localhost instead of IPv6 local address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this simple script to allow the cros origin in codeigniter

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    die();
}

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Write it on top of your codeigniter file. It worked for me hopefully will work for you too.